# How do I import a global rule in a sass file without it getting compiled away?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, import, sass

I need to import the `antd` css module, and the following works if I place it in a javascript file:

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
```

However if I place the following in my `global.sass` file:

```
@use '~antd/dist/antd.css'
```

And import it via `import './global.sass'` in my js file, the css doesn't get loaded on the page at all.

How do I load the global imports in my `sass` file instead? Is there some webpack configuration to do this? I'm using `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `postcss-loader`, `sass-loader`.

Comment: try "@import" instead of "@use"

Comment: @user3366943 same thing

Comment: read about here, https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import. take out the .css extension when you import css files into a sass file

Comment: What javascript framework are you using? Simply importing a SCSS file into javascript doesn't tell Webpack to compile it into something that the browser can read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 critical things were needed, one was to place the `@import`s in the global scope, another was to remove the `.css` extension when importing files.

The final solution looked like:

```
\:global
  @import '~antd/dist/antd'
```

I only found out how to use global styles in `.sass` when using the online converter [SCSS to SASS](http://scss2sass.herokuapp.com/converter). The backslash there is necessary.

And thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3366943/user3366943 for this. I didn't quite believe that I needed to remove the `.css` extension, until I got the `\:global` working and read the same thing in the docs at [Sass: @import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import).

---

P.S. Regarding the `@import` being deprecated issue mentioned in [Sass: @import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import), the way to do this without it is by:

```
@use 'sass:meta'

\:global
  @include meta.load-css('~antd/dist/antd')
```

I got this by running `sass-migrator module --migrate-deps frontend/styles/App.sass`.

To have this build properly we must use the `sass` npm package instead of `node-sass`.